# Is it possible to define a range in VBA based on a value given in a cell? And get sum at end of the range in each column at each time

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to define a range in VBA based on a value given in a cell? And get sum at end of the range in each column at each time.

Here i have written a code to populate month end date in column “A” starting from row A17:A300 for 300 months based on starting date and ending date. Cell B1 is starting date, cell B2 is ending date and cell B3 is number of months.

```
Sub GenerateDates()
Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date
Dim currentDate As Date
startDate = Range("b1").Value
endDate = Range("b2").Value
currentDate = startDate
Range("a17").Select
Do Until currentDate = endDate
     ActiveCell.Value = currentDate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
       'currentDate = DateAdd("m", 1, currentDate)
      currentDate = DateSerial(Year(currentDate), Month(currentDate) + 2, 0)
      Loop
End Sub
```

Now I want to extend the above code to calculate summation at each column starting from column B17:J300 with dynamic range of rows depending on cell B3 For example, I have a dataset with 10 columns, data start from 17th row and a constantly changing number of rows. I have the number of rows in cell B3. Suppose cell B3 indicates the number of rows is 300, then I be able to Range("B17:j300").Select, but I want the selection of the last cell to be dependent on cell B3. Also I want get sum(“B17:B300”) at “B301” row and like the summation at each column 
So if I change B3 to 50, that the next time I run the macro, B17:j50 will be selected, other previous data in cell above row 50 that is “A51:J300” should be deleted and also I want get sum(“B17:B50”) at “B51” row and like the summation at each column 
 but since I'm new to VBA I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why use VBA? you can do that in a cell formula...

`=SUM(OFFSET(A17,0,0,B9))`

Comment: the number of rows range in data is dynamic and it will change each time, each time i can't use this formula every time since i have to do this exercise N no.of times

Comment: thanks for you reply... but it is missing dynamic range of rows.. Suppose cell B3 indicates the number of rows is 300, then I be able to Range("B17:j300").Select, but I want the selection of the last cell to be dependent on cell B3. Also I want get sum(“B17:B300”) at “B301” row and like the summation at each column So if I change B3 to 50, that the next time I run the macro, B17:j50 will be selected, other previous data in cell above row 50 that is “A51:J300” should be deleted and also I want get sum(“B17:B50”) at “B51” row

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your above code is working then add following lines at the end of your code.

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B" & lastRow + 1 & ":J" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(B17:B" & lastRow & ")"
```

or to be more efficient

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change Sheet1 to your data sheet
With ws
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("B" & lastRow + 1 & ":J" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(B17:B" & lastRow & ")"
End With
```

***EDIT :*** Provided your code works you can write it as

```
Sub GenerateDates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date, currentDate As Date
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        startDate = .Range("B1").Value
        endDate = .Range("B2").Value
        currentDate = startDate
        Set rng = .Range("A17") 'Range("a17").Select
        Do Until currentDate = endDate
            rng.Value = currentDate 'ActiveCell.Value = currentDate
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0) 'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            currentDate = DateSerial(Year(currentDate), Month(currentDate) + 2, 0)
        Loop
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B" & lastRow + 1 & ":J" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(B17:B" & lastRow & ")"
    End With
End Sub
```

Instead of

```
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
.Range("B" & lastRow + 1 & ":J" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(B17:B" & lastRow & ")"
```

you can also write

```
.Range("B" & rng.Row & ":J" & rng.Row).Formula = "=SUM(B17:B" & lastRow & ")"
```

Comment: thanks for you reply... but it is missing dynamic range of rows.. Suppose cell B3 indicates the number of rows is 300, then I be able to Range("B17:j300").Select, but I want the selection of the last cell to be dependent on cell B3. Also I want get sum(“B17:B300”) at “B301” row and like the summation at each column So if I change B3 to 50, that the next time I run the macro, B17:j50 will be selected, other previous data in cell above row 50 that is “A51:J300” should be deleted and also I want get sum(“B17:B50”) at “B51” row